# Difficulty Adding a "Play Again!" Button to this snake game

Tags: javascript, button

I've been trying to figure out how I can add a play again button to refresh the page after a player has lost. This is a classic snake game. I followed a tutorial on it and but they never said anything about a Play Again button. Any help would be appreciated. Nothing too complicated though please, I'm still learning.

````
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

class SnakePart {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

let speed = 7;

let tileCount = 20;
let tileSize = canvas.width / tileCount - 2;

let headX = 10;
let headY = 10;
const snakeParts = [];
let tailLength = 2;

let appleX = 5;
let appleY = 5;

let inputsXVelocity = 0;
let inputsYVelocity = 0;

let xVelocity = 0;
let yVelocity = 0;

let score = 0;

const gulpSound = new Audio("gulp.mp3");

//game loop
function drawGame() {
    xVelocity = inputsXVelocity;
    yVelocity = inputsYVelocity;

    changeSnakePosition();
    let result = isGameOver();
    if (result) {
        return;
    }

    clearScreen();

    checkAppleCollision();
    drawApple();
    drawSnake();

    drawScore();

    if (score > 5) {
        speed = 9;
    }
    if (score > 10) {
        speed = 11;
    }

    setTimeout(drawGame, 1000 / speed);
}

function isGameOver() {
    let gameOver = false;

    if (yVelocity === 0 && xVelocity === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    //walls
    if (headX < 0) {
        gameOver = true;
    } else if (headX === tileCount) {
        gameOver = true;
    } else if (headY < 0) {
        gameOver = true;
    } else if (headY === tileCount) {
        gameOver = true;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < snakeParts.length; i++) {
        let part = snakeParts[i];
        if (part.x === headX && part.y === headY) {
            gameOver = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (gameOver) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.font = "50px Verdana";

        if (gameOver) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.font = "50px Verdana";

            var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, 0);
            gradient.addColorStop("0", " magenta");
            gradient.addColorStop("0.5", "blue");
            gradient.addColorStop("1.0", "red");
            // Fill with gradient
            ctx.fillStyle = gradient;

            ctx.fillText("Game Over!", canvas.width / 6.5, canvas.height / 2);
        }

        ctx.fillText("Game Over!", canvas.width / 6.5, canvas.height / 2);
    }

    return gameOver;
}

function drawScore() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.font = "10px Verdana";
    ctx.fillText("Score " + score, canvas.width - 50, 10);
}

function clearScreen() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function drawSnake() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    for (let i = 0; i < snakeParts.length; i++) {
        let part = snakeParts[i];
        ctx.fillRect(part.x * tileCount, part.y * tileCount, tileSize, tileSize);
    }

    snakeParts.push(new SnakePart(headX, headY)); //put an item at the end of the list next to the head
    while (snakeParts.length > tailLength) {
        snakeParts.shift(); // remove the furthet item from the snake parts if have more than our tail size.
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
    ctx.fillRect(headX * tileCount, headY * tileCount, tileSize, tileSize);
}

function changeSnakePosition() {
    headX = headX + xVelocity;
    headY = headY + yVelocity;
}

function drawApple() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(appleX * tileCount, appleY * tileCount, tileSize, tileSize);
}

function checkAppleCollision() {
    if (appleX === headX && appleY == headY) {
        appleX = Math.floor(Math.random() * tileCount);
        appleY = Math.floor(Math.random() * tileCount);
        tailLength++;
        score++;
        gulpSound.play();
    }
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);

function keyDown(event) {
    //up
    if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 87) {
        //87 is w
        if (inputsYVelocity == 1) return;
        inputsYVelocity = -1;
        inputsXVelocity = 0;
    }

    //down
    if (event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 83) {
        // 83 is s
        if (inputsYVelocity == -1) return;
        inputsYVelocity = 1;
        inputsXVelocity = 0;
    }

    //left
    if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 65) {
        // 65 is a
        if (inputsXVelocity == 1) return;
        inputsYVelocity = 0;
        inputsXVelocity = -1;
    }

    //right
    if (event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68) {
        //68 is d
        if (inputsXVelocity == -1) return;
        inputsYVelocity = 0;
        inputsXVelocity = 1;
    }
}

drawGame();```
````

Comment: Refactor this by introducing a function that sets default values for most variables, speed, velocity, snake parts etc. Also,  reset the timer. And just call this.

Comment: put your set initial variable state to separate function and run in on the beginning of drawGame(). Then to reaster game you have to call again drawGame.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to refresh the page would be just:

```
window.location.reload(false)
```

Source:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/location-reload-method-how-to-reload-a-page-in-javascript/

I would suggest that simply reloading the page is not a great way to implement a play again feature but I appreciate the creativity of it.